# Elasticsearch - Aggregations on part of bool query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Say I have this bool query:

```
"bool" : {
    "should" : [
        { "term" : { "FirstName" : "Sandra" } },
        { "term" : { "LastName" : "Jones" } }
     ],
     "minimum_should_match" : 1
}
```

meaning I want to match all the people with first name Sandra OR last name Jones.

Now, is there any way that I can get perform an aggregation on all the documents that matched the first term only?

For example, I want to get all of the unique values of "Prizes" that anybody named Sandra has. Normally I'd just do:

```
"query": {
    "match": {
        "FirstName": "Sandra"
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "Prizes": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "Prizes"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to combine the two so I only have to perform a single query which returns all of the people with first name Sandra or last name Jones, AND an aggregation only on the people with first name Sandra?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Why you need to do that?

Comment: @Lax Well I need all the people with first name Sandra, all the people with last name Jones and an aggregation on all the people with first name Sandra anyway, so I was wondering if I could merge them into a single query instead of two (all the people with first name Sandra + aggregation, and all the people with last name Jones). Just wishful thinking I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use post_filter.
Please refer the following query. Post_filter will make sure that your bool should clause don't effect your aggregation scope.

Aggregations are filtered based on main query as well, but they are unaffected by post_filter. Please refer to the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html)

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20,
    "aggs": {
        "filtered_lastname": {
            "filter": {
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "FirstName": "sandra"
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "prizes": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "Prizes",
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "post_filter": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "term": {
                    "FirstName": "Sandra"
                }
            }, {
                "term": {
                    "LastName": "Jones"
                }
            }],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Running a filter inside the aggs before aggregating on prizes can help you achieve your desired usecase.

Thanks 
Hope this helps